Firebase cloud function works on dev but not on prod because of ECONNRESET
This code works perfectly on dev with the following command
"dev": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --only functions,firestore --import=./firestore-data --export-on-exit firestore-data ",

On local it will run, download the file and upload it to the PROD storage. However when I deploy it I get the following error in the middle of the execution : ECONNRESET
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": "read ECONNRESET",
        "name": "Error",
        "stack": "Error: read ECONNRESET\n    at AxiosError.from (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:836:14)\n    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:3086:25)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/workspace/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:38:24)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at Axios.request (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:3876:41)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async test3Handler (/workspace/lib/apis/test-3.handler.js:11:26)",
        "config": {
            "transitional": {
                "silentJSONParsing": true,
                "forcedJSONParsing": true,
                "clarifyTimeoutError": false
            },
            "adapter": [
                "xhr",
                "http"
            ],
            "transformRequest": [
                null
            ],
            "transformResponse": [
                null
            ],
            "timeout": 0,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "maxBodyLength": -1,
            "env": {},
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "User-Agent": "axios/1.6.8",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
            },
            "method": "get",
            "responseType": "arraybuffer",
            "url": "https://rr1---sn-nv47zn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1712018524&ei=_P8KZsHvCt-E6dsP1IqbmAI&ip=94.26.17.10&id=o-AJHRH1ekJWwq8Nl5ZP6s7n3rYYkhvVtmmHWRH7cVJzB0&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D&mh=o6&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-nv47zn7y%2Csn-nv47lnly&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=24&initcwndbps=1842500&spc=UWF9f6U1k-vWdUjdr7yE72h2VHaYuS2UbYRIvFE7kjHOnrw&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=hhMfL3OLrj-yDzgb2aQSs4MQ&gir=yes&clen=976151&dur=60.181&lmt=1711511253031138&mt=1711996637&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=51141541&c=WEB&sefc=1&txp=4432434&n=IRzfNFd8Baa31w&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALClDIEwRAIgDK3OK_hFqw-IrUU0bfOy812XLZnXcJF1nErEl6FoxiUCIBO6MHyLDkkY4xGnt5lWRAUQ1m1OIIgrt2ESYMvaIDeC&sig=AJfQdSswRgIhAKyLr2iYg9jWlKjwwtLuMQz1zd22dN_44CESRr8aSY6lAiEA-l8rwlm7Mda92hwx0TDSMf_TCoAbYIc7OQRKthgznD0%3D"
        },
        "code": "ECONNRESET",
        "status": null
    }
}

import 'dotenv/config';
import { firebaseAdmin } from './firebase/init-firebase-admin';
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import axios from 'axios/index';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase-admin/storage';

export const app: Application = express();

app.all('/test3', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios(
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      'https://rr1---sn-nv47zn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1712018524&ei=_P8KZsHvCt-E6dsP1IqbmAI&ip=94.26.17.10&id=o-AJHRH1ekJWwq8Nl5ZP6s7n3rYYkhvVtmmHWRH7cVJzB0&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D&mh=o6&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-nv47zn7y%2Csn-nv47lnly&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=24&initcwndbps=1842500&spc=UWF9f6U1k-vWdUjdr7yE72h2VHaYuS2UbYRIvFE7kjHOnrw&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=hhMfL3OLrj-yDzgb2aQSs4MQ&gir=yes&clen=976151&dur=60.181&lmt=1711511253031138&mt=1711996637&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=51141541&c=WEB&sefc=1&txp=4432434&n=IRzfNFd8Baa31w&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALClDIEwRAIgDK3OK_hFqw-IrUU0bfOy812XLZnXcJF1nErEl6FoxiUCIBO6MHyLDkkY4xGnt5lWRAUQ1m1OIIgrt2ESYMvaIDeC&sig=AJfQdSswRgIhAKyLr2iYg9jWlKjwwtLuMQz1zd22dN_44CESRr8aSY6lAiEA-l8rwlm7Mda92hwx0TDSMf_TCoAbYIc7OQRKthgznD0%3D',
      {
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      }
    );

    console.log('data', data.byteLength);

    const file = getStorage(firebaseAdmin).bucket().file('/audio5.opus');
    await file.save(data, {
      contentType: 'audio/ogg',
      onUploadProgress: (progress) => {
        console.log('progress', progress);
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: e });
  }

  return res.json({ success: true });
});

export const api = onRequest({ region: 'europe-west1', timeoutSeconds: 1.5 * 60 }, app);


I don't understand why ?
The same thing happens if I use a stream - I get 90% of the file when deployed and then it hangs.
